# How can I populate a QtableView from a list of dataclass instances

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

```
@dataclass
class Nc:
   x : int
listNc=[Nc(1),Nc(2)]
```

How can I create a class to cast a list of Nc into a Qtableview ?

```
class NcTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    """
    Class to populate Nc table view from a list of Nc instance
    """
...
view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
model=NcTableModel(listNc)
view.setModel(model)
view.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Nc:
cst: str
pNbr : str
desc : str


class NcTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

 def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
    QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
    self._data = data

 def rowCount(self, parent):
    return len(self._data)

 def columnCount(self, parent):
    return len(Nc.__dataclass_fields__.keys())

 def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    if not index.isValid():
        return QVariant()
    elif role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
        print( "edit mode" )
        return None
    elif role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return None
    return astuple(self._data[index.row()])[index.column()]
```